# How to know how many times and where any CSS selector is being used in whole site?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

for example:

I want to know if i change anything in this selector then how many places it will effect? How many page are using this selector and which places?

```
#annualReportInvestorContainer p a {.........}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) and [DustMeSelectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) can help you there. See their docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var selector = '#annualReportInvestorContainer p a';
 alert('The selector "' + selector + '" reference to '+ ($(selector).size()) +' element(s)! :O');
});
```

Comment: will it generate any report, pls tell how to use? how to check whole site?

Answer (score -1):

I always use `grep`.

Comment: How can you grep a slice of the DOM structure?

Comment: Their answer wasn't totally clear, but I'm sure they meant using grep to search in all his files. For example, searching for `id="annualReportInvestorContainer"` would find you where that ID is being used.